# PHP - get information form comments in php files

Tags: php

Please tell me an easy and effective way for reading or getting information (whatever it is?) form the comment in php files, Whereas I know wordpress use this features.

Like I have a folder called `theme` and there are three files with this comment:

In first file

```
/* Template Name: page */
```

In second file

```
/* Template Name: category */
```

In third file

```
/* Template Name: Tags */
```

Then how whold I get `page`,`category`,`tags` in an array,
Please give a solution

Thanks for your time

Comment: Less resource consuming than what? (ie, what are you doing that you want it faster and less consuming than?)

Comment: Reflection can get at this.

Comment: have you tried parse php files code source ?

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae No, Please give me an example

Comment: @user1983017, check my answer bellow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pare the php files you can do as:

```
$str = file_get_contents("/path/to/file1");
```

than you complete php file code is there, and you will need to use some regex to get the comments content

---

#### example:

lets assume the `$str` have your php source code, the regex might be something like:

```
$str = "/* Template Name: page */\n bla bla blah";

preg_match( "#/\* Template Name: (\w*) \*/#", $str, $m);

var_dump( $m );
```

---

previous code output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(25) "/* Template Name: page */"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "page"
}
```

what you need is stored in `$m[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = file_get_contents($filename);
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
foreach($tokens as $token){
    if( ($token[0] == T_COMMENT || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT)
       && preg_match('/Template Name: (.*)/',$token[1],$match){
       echo "Template name is ".$match[1];
    }
}
```